# Creating tabs using abp-tabs with angular in abp commercial

Tags: abp

I am trying to create a module in my abp commercial solution with a horizontal wizard similar to this https://x.leptontheme.com/top-menu/custom-pages/wizard-horizontal.

I understood that I could use abp-tabs but I can’t get it to recognise this tag.

Can someone advise how to do this?

Comment: Hello, can you look for usage examples on the relevant [site](https://bootstrap-taghelpers.abp.io/Components/Tabs#)?